# Change index of array into desirable order issue

Tags: php

Hi I have an array that is indexed 0-13 its key valued so each index has an array of its own nested, I want to be able to change the order of it to [0,2,1,3,4,5,7,6,8,10,9,11,13,12].
here is my attempt but it doesnt work.

```
var (array)
1   
array
id  1
datemodified    2005-01-19 
2   
array
id  2
datemodified    2005-01-19
```

thats the struture of the array I want to change, I want to change the order of the array .

Comment: 0-13 == -13. What did you expect to happen? Show what your array is really like, and what you want to achieve

Comment: What does `$newarr[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]` mean? What does `$oldarr[0,2,1,3,4,5,7,6,8,10,9,11,13,12]` mean? Show what you have and what you want, not some incomprehensible invalid code

Comment: @lorenzo.marcon it's PHP just fine, only >= 5.4

Comment: @Kolink: Yeah, the syntax is not valid. But `[i, j, k....]` by itself is valid array syntax, that's what I am talking about. The question has been edited too.

Comment: the array notation could be good (at least for initialization), but that syntax isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess what you mean:

```
$oldarr = array(0,2,1,3,4,5,7,6,8,10,9,11,13,12);
$oldarrKeys = array(0,2,1,3,4,5,7,6,8,10,9,11,13,12);
$newarr = array();
foreach($oldarrKeys as $key) {
    $newarr[] = $oldarr[$key];
}
```

Comment: @Baker actually each index has an array of its own. I just want to change the order of the array's index

Comment: Please, Squirtle, unless you show us exactly what you mean, we can only guess: if you can't explain your problem clearly, then it's difficult for us to help

Answer (score 0):

Define your new order like so:

```
$neworder = [0,2,1,3,4,5,7,6,8,10,9,11,13,12];
```

Now use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array-multisort):

```
array_multisort($neworder,$oldarr);
```

Comment: actually each index has an array of its own. I just want to change the order of the array's index

Comment: That's what this does. Have you even tried it before dismissing my code?